# Why do the elements of the array change when they shouldn't?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am writing code for Merge sort, I use object arrays with lists which are then sorted and merged, I know it's a bit strange and there is probably a better way to do it. When I recurse back to function in the code below, there a more elements than there should be, and I just don't get why it happens.

```
public static void RecurseSort(Array arr)
{
    Array ForWork = arr;

    if (ForWork.Length == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("recurs finish");
    }
    else
    {
        List<object> ForRecurse = new List<object>();
        Array arrCopy = new object[ForWork.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < ForWork.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            List<int> r1 = (List<int>)ForWork.GetValue(i);
            List<int> r2 = (List<int>)ForWork.GetValue(i + 1);

            if (i == ForWork.Length - 3)
            {
                List<int> r3 =
                (List<int>)ForWork.GetValue(ForWork.Length - 1);

                r2.Add(r3[0]);
            }

            ForRecurse.Add(CompareAndMerge(r1, r2));
        }

        arrCopy = ForRecurse.ToArray();
        RecurseSort(arrCopy);
    }
}
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

So the arrCopy has the correct number of elements but literally when I press 'continue' in the visual studio debbuger, arr[3] has count of 3, when it should have been 2.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the code and step through it, watching the values in the debugger as you go, and it should become clear. This is an important skill to learn. The better you get at it, the less you'll need to do it (you'll be able to do it in your head)

Comment: ```Array ForWork = arr;```: What do you expect to happen there?

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer - split it to smaller problems and solve them.

## Copy

How do you copy data from array A to array B, for example what will be the result of:

```
int[] src  = { 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270 };
int[] dest = { 17, 18, 19, 20 };
int length = 2;

Array.Copy(src, 4, dest, 2, length);
```

## Arithmetics

How do you divide array to 2 - divide by 2, but if the size is uneven ex: 7, what will be the result of:

```
var length = 7;
var result = length / 2;
```

Type constraints

```
var length = 7d;
var result = length / 2;
```

## Merging 2 sorted array

In merge sort you use another sort, for example **insertion sort** if you have only few elements left, ex: 20. So if you are given following insertion sort, how do you split array of 37 random numbers to 2 partisions, sort them and merge them.

```
  static class InsertionSort<T> where T : IComparable {
    public static void Sort(T[] entries, Int32 first, Int32 last) {
      for (var index = first + 1; index <= last; index++)
        insert(entries, first, index);
    }

    private static void insert(T[] entries, Int32 first, Int32 index) {
      var entry = entries[index];
      while (index > first && entries[index - 1].CompareTo(entry) > 0)
        entries[index] = entries[--index];
      entries[index] = entry;
    }
  }
```

In addition, debugger is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say as you did not provide the full text of the working example. But I suspect that you keeping references to objects in the array when you should not.
But most importantly I suggest you rewrite your code so it does not use casts. Try using List of List - `List<List<int>>` - it will be strongly typed and clear your algorithm. Also, I suggest writing it for concrete type to sort - `int` and later moving to Generic implementation with your method that will accept type `<T>` to sort.